# Change audio pitch in a video in actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have been looking everywhere but no joy so I thought I'd ask here.

I am looking for a way to change the pitch of a video at runtime.

I know it can be done on audio but I am looking for a way to do this while playing video.

Can anyone help or guide me in the right direction?

Comment: Apparently you cannot do this, as `StageVideo` does not export audio stream.

Comment: Could you separate the audio and video tracks?